# How do I set the app.config for a web based .NET app?

Tags: asp.net, .net, internet-explorer

Unfortunately the organization I work for has a legacy .net application made in XP era, we are in the process of updating but that may not take place until a few months or even the end of the year. This .net app is web based and requires .net framework 3.5, it also needs IE9 or less to run, anything beyond this and the app will break and stop working.  Somehow the update for framework 4.5.2 installed, I uninstalled it but for some reason it keep reinstalling by itself over night. I uninstall the update and the next morning I will come into work and it will reinstall. I was reading that the app.config could be set for .net apps to set the parameters of what framework they use.  I am not sure where the app.config file would be located for this app or how I could find it for a web based .net app?

Comment: Are you just asking what a `web.config` file is?  It should be in the root of the web application.  (And there could be more in any given folder of the web application.)

Comment: In a web based application is called web.config and if you cannot find that file then you should study a bit before launching in this task.

Comment: I doubt IE 9 is truly needed. You can probably set the compatibility mode in the browser to IE 9. And you can force it from code by [setting the correct compatibility settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff966528(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Not the web.config I don't have access to the server site.  I read that on the client side you can set limits on the framework, but I do not see how to do this for a web app. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

For an app named Something.exe, the App.config file (if you need one) should be placed in the same folder and named Something.exe.config.

Comment: How do I set this for a web based app?  There is no *.exe.

Comment: In that case, the file should be Web.config, in the same directory as the .dlls.